# Store values from a loop

Tags: r, loops

I am simulating dice throws, and would like to save the output in a single object, but cannot find a way to do so. I tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154748/store-values-in-for-loop), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430325/assign-loop-not-working-for-plot), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667478/r-how-can-i-save-the-value-of-print), but they do not seem to answer my question.

Here is my attempt to assign the result of a 20 x 3 trial to an object:

```
set.seed(1) 
Twenty = for(i in 1:20){   
  trials = sample.int(6, 3, replace = TRUE)   
  print(trials)   
  i = i+1 
}
print(Twenty)
```

What I do not understand is why I cannot recall the function after it is run?

I also tried using `return` instead of `print` in the function:

```
Twenty = for(i in 1:20){
  trials = sample.int(6, 3, replace = TRUE)
  return(trials)
  i = i+1
}
print(Twenty)
```

or creating an empty matrix first:

```
mat = matrix(0, nrow = 20, ncol = 3)
mat    
for(i in 1:20){
  mat[i] = sample.int(6, 3, replace = TRUE)
  print(mat)
  i = i+1
}
```

but they seem to be worse (as I do not even get to see the trials).

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: What is the programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your attempts:

1) A loop is not a function nor an object in R, so it doesn't make sense to assign a loop to a variable

2) When you have a loop `for(i in 1:20)`, the loop will increment `i` so it doesn't make sense to add `i = i + 1`.

Your last attempt implemented correctly would look like this:

```
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 20, ncol = 3)
for(i in 1:20){
     mat[i, ] = sample.int(6, 3, replace = TRUE)
}
print(mat)
```

I personally would simply do

```
matrix(sample.int(6, 20 * 3, replace = TRUE), nrow = 20)
```

(since all draws are independent and with replacement, it doesn't matter if you make 3 draws 20 times or simply 60 draws)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in most programming languages one does not assign objects to `for` loops as they are not formally function objects. One uses loops to interact iteratively on existing objects. However, R maintains the *apply* family that saves iterative outputs to objects in same length as inputs.

Consider `lapply` (**l**ist apply) for list output or `sapply` (**s**implified apply) for matrix output:

```
# LIST OUTPUT
Twenty <- lapply(1:20, function(x) sample.int(6, 3, replace = TRUE))

# MATRIX OUTPUT
Twenty <- sapply(1:20, function(x) sample.int(6, 3, replace = TRUE))
```

And to see your trials, simply print out the object

```
print(Twenty)
```

But since you never use the iterator variable, `x`, consider `replicate` (wrapper to `sapply` which by one argument can output a matrix or a list) that receives size and expression (no sequence inputs or functions) arguments:

```
# MATRIX OUTPUT (DEFAULT)
Twenty <- replicate(20, sample.int(6, 3, replace = TRUE))

# LIST OUTPUT
Twenty <- replicate(20, sample.int(6, 3, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list:

```
Twenty=list()
for(i in 1:20){
  Twenty[[i]] = sample.int(6, 3, replace = TRUE)
}
```